# Windows 7 IE 11 - Issue with MP3 on website not playing. Invalid Source

Tags: windows, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, mp3

I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I'm working on a project that needs to be supported on Windows 7 with browser support for IE11.  I've gotten most of the requirements met but running into an issue with trying to embed an audio clip onto the webpage.  I have tried three different methods and each unsuccessful and saying invalid source.  I have tried with a different mp3 and same results.

Method One:

```
            <object class="ie11" type="audio/mp3" data="****/6036.mp3">
                <param name="src" value="****/6036.mp3" />
                <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />
                <param name="loop" value="0"/>
            </object>
```

Method Two:

```
            <embed type="audio/mp3" src="****/6036.mp3" autoplay="true" autostart="true" width="300" height="50">
```

Method Three:

```
    <audio controls=""><source src="****/6036.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

Has anyone run into this before and any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<audio> tag is not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802319/audio-tag-is-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't notice that post but I had tried everything that was listed under that post as well.